# How to call javascript function (jquery) in a shortcode?

Tags: php, jquery, javascript

Before asking here, I've searched a while and found a tutorial about creating a wordpress plugin with shortcode and javascript calling.

But I'm not able to make it work on my side. The tutorial is [here](https://catn.com/2014/10/06/tutorial-writing-a-simple-wordpress-plugin-from-scratch/)

Basically it is supposed to add a teletype terminal displaying predefined strings. I'm able to follow it to the part where the terminal is drawn. But I do not see where in the code, we are calling the javascript function tomake the "animation". There's a zip to download with all the sources, and teletype javasources (not minimized) can be found [here](http://teletype.rocks/)

So, my problem is that I do not catch how to call a javascript/jquery function from a php file.

Has anyone the possibility to try the tutorial out and give me an advice on how to complete the missing parts?

I think that the part where I'm lost is the last one : Make data available to JavaScript

I've of course contacted the author but I still have no answer and it is very frustrating no to be able to finish the work.

I guess there must be something in the php part:

```
<input <?php echo implode( ' ', $atts ); ?> />
<?php if ( array_key_exists( 'description', $options ) ) : ?>
<?php esc_html_e( $options['description'] ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But I'm not finding what...

Thanks.

Sylvain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) with `$in_footer` parameter set to `true`, when loading scripts with your shortcode. To pass data from the PHP part of your code to the JS part use [`wp_localize_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'script_name', '/script-location/script.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );  
$data_array = array(
  'key_1' => 'val_1',
  'key_2' => 'val_2'
);
wp_localize_script( 'script_name', 'data_object_name', $data_array );
```

You now can access the data in your script by addressing the data object - for example:

```js
console.log( data_object_name.key_1 );
```